# Failed opening 'NANphp” even though I write in code something else

Tags: php

```
<?php
 include_once(“controller/controller.php”);
 $controller = new controller();
 $controller->result();
```

So,as you see at anove there is include from "controller/controller.php" but the error messages are like this -

- include_once(NANphp”): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/vhosts/www.virtuelles****.com/*******/indexsec.php on line 2
- Warning: Division by zero in /srv/www/vhosts/www.virtuelles-*****.com/****/indexsec.php on line 2
- Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'NANphp”' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /srv/www/vhosts/www.virtuelles-***.com/******/indexsec.php on line 2
- Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'controller' not found in /srv/www/vhosts/www.virtuelles*****.com/****/indexsec.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/www/vhosts/www.virtuelles-****.com/******/indexsec.php on line 3
- stars are censore

I know I dont give much code but I think its not about code.

Comment: Those are not the correct quotes: `“controller/controller.php”` Use "regular" double quotes `"`

Comment: I tried it too but still the error is same.

Comment: Unrelated: _if_ you really need to "censor" words/domains make sure you do it in all lines and not accidentally forget one ... ;)

Comment: The error is the same? I doubt that. Did you try single quotes? `include_once('controller/controller.php');`? Do you have an editor plugin running that replaces quotes or something?

Comment: @brombeer oh no haha, well its order from our manager. I dont do that when i do personal stuff. Thanx for letting me know

Comment: @brombeer Yes already tried it too. And no I use Atom editor. But I accidently pressed wrong quotes. But I checked other codes and they are alright.